# restricting the user to enter data in only one among all text fields available in jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, struts

Rs. 5   Rs.10   Rs.20   Rs.50   Rs.100  Rs.500  Rs.1000

There are seven text fields mentioned as above in a row of the table.
The requirement is we need to restrict the user to enter data in only one of the seven text fields displayed.Remember that there are more than one row of such which were iterated  using `logic:iterate`.

Please share the code for validating it.

Comment: Please show some code!!! also what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

As you have not provided the complete details, I am considering it as a Web Application, if it is not a web application then similar logic can be implemented in whatever technology it is.

```
1. TextField 1 onFocus="validate()"
2. TextField 2 onFocus="validate()"
3. TextField 3 onFocus="validate()"
4. TextField 4 onFocus="validate()"
5. TextField 5 onFocus="validate()"
-----

function validate(){

var a1 = document.getElementById("textField1");
var a2 = document.getElementById("textField2");
var a3 = document.getElementById("textField3");
var a4 = document.getElementById("textField4");
var a5 = document.getElementById("textField5");

if(a1.trim() == ''){
  //hide all textFields other then textField1
}

if(a2.trim() == ''){
  //hide all textFields other then textField2
}


}
```

this is one way you can do it, if number of textfield is fixed and less in number. if it is more then some dynamic logic will be needed.

Also for dynamic stuff, you can pass id on validate(this) call and simply keep that and hide others in function.

I missed your iterate stuff,

in that case you can just pass row id to validate function and in the function you try executing for loop for 7 times and similarly hide all the textfield having id ending with row id given(this depends on logic you have given an id to your textfields.)